# android studio doesn't create navigation drawer activity

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation, navigation-drawer

I just want to create a navigation drawer activity. When I Right click on app > new > activity > navigation drawer activity, nothing happens! it just creates a xml file in menu directory. i tried deleting android studio and user preferences files and reinstalling it, but still having the same problem. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

First of all , you should create a new activity called navigation drawer activity , you just need to follow these steps : file > new > activity > navigation drawer activity . Then you can modify the xml content and create a navigation drawer like you want .

Answer (score 0):

first create a new project with navigation drawer.
 `file > new project>navigation drawer activity`. and then add content to the template

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all navigation drawer activity files are safely deleted. This means all resource xml files. Also check whether the activity is created in AndroidManifest.xml, if it is remove the said activity.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting all the xml and java files related to navigation drawer you even need to Delete these lines:
"implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.2'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.2'"

in you app.gradle module,then try creating a navigation drawer activity named MainActivity2.

Answer (score 0):

May be the android studio version you are using has problems. I think you are using android studio canary version. Try using stable version. If you are already using stable version then clear data and all the details and start project again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have deleted all the files related to your previous navigation drawer activity. !!
And also remove the dependencies that were added during your first import.